# How to delete everything?

Tags: factory-reset, restore, delete

My phone is either infected or simply has an error in one of my apps and gives me the com.android.phone stopped error (plus the one like 44 01 21, don't remember exactly).

I took phone to the service, they didn't fix it. I deleted all memory card, did factory reset like 5 times, but some apps are on internal memory and they stay there. How to completely wipe it all out?

I made a back up of personal data, that's the only thing I want to keep. How to delete everything else correctly?

Comment: delete everything except default apps, preinstalled apps.

Comment: Are you sure you did a [factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)? Because if you did, none of the apps you've installed yourself into "phone memory" should have survived that, neither should any of your data. Pre-installed apps of course remain, as they are installed in read-only system storage.

Comment: In settings I choose - do factory reset and erase SD card. So I think I did

Comment: Affirmative, that should really have done the job. So either the implementation there is faulty (please take a look at the [tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for alternatives) – or you confused some of the pre-installed apps with those you've installed. After the factory reset, did the device come up with the registration dialogs (asking you to create a Google account etc.)? Have you tried to factory-reset via the recovery menu?

Comment: I only know how to do the factory reset through recovery menu. Yes, I got the registration dialog and logged in my account. I did not confuse these apps, for example the apps for my banks couldn't have been pre-installed or google really knows too much about me and my finances.

Comment: Have you checked the "Backup to Google" option? If so, your apps might have been re-installed automatically once you've configured your account again.

Comment: Not sure about before, but now it is selected. Maybe I should try factory reset after disabling this. I can restore personal data from computer. Although, I think I want to downgrade kitkat (since SD card is inaccessible in 4.4), can I do that or only the technical support service (last time they have my phone downgraded) can do that?

Comment: Just make sure to not check it on initialization (i.e. *after* the factory-reset, when the wizard guides you to setup your Google account on the device). So you still have the latest backup stored, just not re-stored ;)

Comment: Already unchecked it and it warned that it will delete  the backup. So too late, but I only care about my personal data and I will back it up to computer/sd card and retry the factory reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Izzy for the solution.

The problem with the factory reset was that google back up copy included some apps and they were reinstalled. So you have to untick the back up to google on the recovery menu and make sure to untick it when you are starting up your phone again. It is checked as default.

It even solved the issue I had with the dictionary app, as I could re choose the dictionary I need.

Answer (score 1):

The apps on the internal memory are system apps. They can be deleted only if you have root.

Comment: I don't mean the system apps. I mean the apps I installed, most of them are installed in phone memory(so widgets could work), I transferred some to memory card, but still a lot are remaining. I'd like to wipe them out completely. Factory reset doesn't delete any apps. I want my phone do be in the condition I received it, before I did anything.

Comment: @LauraLG Factory reset is *supposed* to delete all your apps and data, leaving the phone in the state it came from the factory.

Comment: I think that happened only after the service guys did it, reflashing device or whatever it's called. It even downgraded the kitkat version, unlike when I do factory reset. Unfortunately, the service guy and me decided to restore the phone. Personal data was restored ok, but app data not - some of the apps got restored.